# JavaScript - Truncate number in a String in all possible ways

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want a function to truncate all zeros from a number in a String, a number a String can be bigger than JavaScript's Floating Point, which means that parseFloat is *not* an option.

As I define truncate, I mean to remove all possible unnecessary zeros and to add all possible necessary zeros, and also take care of decimal cases, some examples:

```
01 -> 1
.04 -> 0.04
.30 -> 0.3
10 -> 10
0.0 -> 0
23. -> 23
00 -> 0
24.560 -> 24.56
```

I highly prefer RegExp, with multiple replace's for easy understanding.

**This edit was made *after* your answers, *but* this is a more detailed version to avoid confusion.**

Comment: Convert the string to number, then back to string, if you necessary need a string.

Comment: `( +"02.032010" ).toString()`

Comment: @OP: you should **really** accept another answer. You have accepted the worst possible solution.

Comment: Why do you ***really*** care?

Comment: Why you are leaning towards regex?

Comment: Because it seems pretty much like the fastest way to fix this.

Comment: Its in fact the slowest. See you have asked this question 22 hours ago and still couldn't find a solution. This is because you want to use regex no matter what the problem is.

Comment: What's the problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression solution:

```
(0+str).replace(/^0+(?=\d)|\.0*$|(\.\d*?)0+$/g, '$1');
```

Basically, we add a zero at the beginning to avoid trailing dot, and then we remove zeros:

- `^0+(?=\d)` removes zeros at the beginning.
- `\.0*$` removes a dot followed by zeros until the end.
- `(\.\d*?)0+$` removes zeros at the end, only if they are after the dot.

Comment: Can you fix so that 23. -> 23 and .04 -> 0.04 too in the regex?

Answer (score 5):

Just coerce it to a number with a plus sign, as what you're really looking for is to convert strings to valid numbers in javascript

```
+"00.020" // 0.02

+"02.032010" // 2.03201
```

or use `parseFloat`, `Number()` or any other method that does the same thing

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9HD6/1/)

Comment: Further reading on the [unary `+` arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Comment: @Murplyx - A floating point 52 bit mantissa as used by javascript only supports 2^53, which is 9007199254740992, and that's the highest number available. If you need numbers that are larger than this you'll have issues with just about everything, and you should break the numbers down and do bitwise calculations, not use regular expressions on strings, as that will never get you anywhere and cause more issues.

Comment: This has already been solved by the way, no need to solve it again, here's an implementation -> http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/jsbn.js

Comment: I have got subtraction, addition and multiplication now by my self nty

Comment: @Murplyx - my answer still stands, but in your examples now `'.'` is not valid, it's not a number so it will return `NaN` (as it should) and *not* a zero. To circumvent that you can `|| 0` (OR NULL), see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/W9HD6/2/**. As for numbers larger than 2^53, there is no good way to handle that, and as I've said before I would suggest a library that can handle large numbers, not just treating them as strings instead.

Comment: I am **making** a library that can hold large numbers, and maybe then there's a solution that uses arrays, by splitting the string. So, maybe your answer stands, but it is still wrong, I mean, don't you wanna help me?

Comment: @Murplyx - Okay, so you're **making** a library to handle large numbers, and again, using strings and regex to handle big numbers will make your library fail miserably. There are already libraries available, and they use bitwise, hex etc. to handle numbers larger than 2^53, and I've linked to the source code of one of those libraries above, made by students at Stanford. Who would ever want to use a library that treats numbers as strings, and uses regex for parsing, when there's libraries available that uses bitwise operations to do the same thing.

Comment: I want to create a library that treats numbers as strings, btw how does bitwise big numbers work?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
> parseFloat("02.032010")
2.03201
> parseFloat("00.020")
0.02
>
```

Comment: Edited question my question, if you can answer to it now, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: My solution [still works](http://pastie.org/9219448)! Do you know any sample for which `parseFloat` does not work? Let me know.

Comment: I want it back to String too, but that's easy with toString(), now for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3jNV3/

Comment: Use `.toFixed` instead of toString. But with a correct number of digits

Comment: That's a correct number of digits, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = parseInt("00.020" , 10);
```

From here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Always specify a radix! `parseInt("...", 10);`

Comment: This will destroy the decimals though.

Comment: Please do not reference W3Schools, as they are in no way related to any groups that determine the standards of web tools, and they are [not always reliable](http://www.w3fools.com/). Instead, the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) has high quality docs, or (for JavaScript) you can use the [ECMAScript language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2).

Answer (score -2):

```
myDecimalString.replace(/(?:(\.\d+?)0+|\.0*)([Ee][+\-]?\d+)?$/, '$1$2')
```

should do it assuming for a string that roughly matches [JavaScript's numerical literal format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Floating-point_literals).

The `(\.\d*?)0+` captures in group `$1` any decimal point and any run of digits that don't participate in a run of trailing zeroes.

The `|\.0*` handles the case where there is a trailing decimal point but no digits.

The `([Ee]...)` captures any exponent in group `$2`.

The substitution `$1$2` preserves the useful part of the fraction followed by any exponent.

That leaves the case where `.0` truncates to the empty string.  We can solve that problem and format inputs like `".5"` nicely via another replace:

```
.replace(/^([+\-])?([.eE]|$)/, '$010$02')
```

which uses `$01` to preserve any starting sign and `$02` to preserve whatever occurs after the integer component while inserting a `0` when there's no integer part.

---

```
var strs = ['10', '10.0', '0.5', '0.50',  '0.500', '1.0e6', '123', '.7', '.2', '.0'];
function trunc(myDecimalString) {
  return myDecimalString
      .replace(
          /(?:(\.\d+?)0+|\.0*)([Ee][+\-]?\d+)?$/, '$1$2')
      .replace(/^([+\-])?([.eE]|$)/, '$010$02');
}
for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; ++i) {
  console.log('%s -> %s', strs[i], trunc(strs[i]));
}
```

demonstrates it in action and logs:

```
10 -> 10
10.0 -> 10
0.5 -> 0.5
0.50 -> 0.5
0.500 -> 0.5
1.0e6 -> 1e6
123 -> 123
.7 -> 0.7 
.2 -> 0.2
.0 -> 0
```

---

## Caveat

This will fail for non-machine generated numbers where `.` is used to [separate groups of digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping) like `1.000.000` for 1 million.

Comment: Why _so_ complicated for something that can be done via native JS methods?

Comment: Aw no, no regexes please.

Comment: Really great because I am making a math library with big numbers so parsing is not an option, but could you also make so that it sets ".02" to "0.02" and ".0" to "0"?

Comment: @Murplyx "so parsing is not an option" - what do you mean by that? String processing and manipulation **is** parsing, and that's exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RPM, go ahead and provide an answer that uses native JS functions and doesn't lead to data-loss for inputs that are not exactly representable as IEEE-754 doubles and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Also an error is that doing it on ".2" will result ".", fail.

Comment: @Murplyx, doing a `.replace(/^([+\-])?(?:[\.eE]|$)/, '$010$02)` should make sure you have the zero left of the decimal.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL?

Comment: Also found that "1234.2".replace(/(?:(.\d+?)0+|.0*)([Ee][+-]?\d+)?$/, '$1$2'); returns "1234."

Comment: @Murplyx, fixed though I can't repeat your problem with `"1234.2"`.

Comment: @Murplyx, I see what's wrong.  You have `.0*`, not `\.0*`.  Maybe you copied mid-edit.

Comment: Error: "0102.0400".replace(/(?:(\.\d+?)0+|\.0*)([Ee][+\-]?\d+)?$/, '$1$2').replace(/^([+\-])?([.eE]|$)/, '$010$02'); returns "0102.0400"

Comment: "066".replace(/(?:(\.\d+?)0+|\.0*)([Ee][+\-]?\d+)?$/, '$1$2').replace(/^([+\-])?([.eE]|$)/, '$010$02'); doesn't return "66" it goes "066" still